# solving the Bernoulli differential equation $y'x^2\ln y-y=xy'$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the Bernoulli differential equation $y'x^2\ln y-y=xy'$, but I didn't succeed cause I can see no way to bring it to a canonical form....are there other ways to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

$$y'x^2\ln y-y=xy'$$
Consider $x'=\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac 1 {y'}$
$$ x^2\ln y-yx'=x$$
Then solve for x the Bernouilli's equation
$$\implies x'y+x=x^2\ln y$$
Or you can integrate this way..
$$(xy)'=(xy)^2 \frac {\ln y}{y^2}$$
It's separable...
$$ \int \frac {d(xy)}{(xy)^2}= \int  \frac {\ln y}{y^2} dy$$
For the integral integrate by part
$$I=\int  \frac {\ln y}{y^2} dy=-\frac {\ln|y|}y+\int \frac {dy}{y^2}$$
$$............$$

Comment: why there is $|y|$, is the abs to be  redundant.

Comment: @LarryEppes I always put the absolute value but you may be right

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{1}{\frac{dx(y)}{dy}}=\frac{y}{\log(y)x(y)-1)x(y)}$$
so
$$-\frac{\frac{dx(y)}{dy}}{x(y)^2}-\frac{1}{yx(y)}=-\frac{\log(y)}{y}$$
substituting $$v(y)=\frac{1}{x(y)}$$
then
$$\frac{v(y)}{dy}-\frac{v(y)}{y}=-\frac{\log(y)}{y}$$ with $$\mu(y)=\frac{1}{y}$$ we get
$$\frac{\frac{dv(y)}{dy}}{y}+\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{y}v(y)\right)=-\frac{\log(y)}{y^2}$$ so
$$\int \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{v(y)}{y}\right)dy=\int-\frac{\log(y)}{y^2}dy$$
so
$$\frac{v(y)}{y}=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{\log(y)}{y}+C_1$$
and we get
$$x(y)=\frac{1}{v(y)}=\frac{1}{\log(y)+yC_1+1}$$